# NSDocument - how to prevent a document from being marked as updated automatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, nsdocument

I have a cocoa app that allows the user to enter a query. I'm using an `NSWebView` with a `TextArea` HTML object. The problem is, as soon as I type anything into the textarea, my document gets marked as updated. Does anyone know of a way to prevent this?

I've verified that using a `NSTextField` does not reproduce this behaviour, but I specifically want to go with the `HTML/TextArea` for styling.

So basically: Can I make it so an `NSDocument` does not get marked as edited unless I manually call:

```
[document updateChangeCount: NSChangeDone];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/webkitsdk-dev/2006/Nov/msg00013.html) on the Apple mailing list seems to match your problem exactly.

The solution suggested is to set a custom undo manager to the webview (sounds like hard work), however a quick-and-dirty hack looks to me like subclassing `updateChangeCount` and perverting things to your way of thinking.